# UWP equivalent of Android's SpannableString with image inside

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Is there a way to implement an image within a TextBlock rather than outside of it? Android has a feature called `SpaanableStringBuilder` which allows the user to create text with different appearances. Does UWP have something similar?

```
MyTextBlock.Text = "Google" + ? + "icon";
```

[image]

Comment: One way is to use a RichTextBlock and embed an InlineUIContainer.

Comment: UWP is complexed. Maybe you can convert the image to a font.

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond said, in UWP, `RichTextBlock` is needed for image and text mixing.

**With Xaml**

```xml
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="Something..."/>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Image Source="your_image_url" Width="20" Height="20"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run Text="Something..."/>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

**With Code**

```cs
var richTextBlock = new RichTextBlock();
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Something..." });
var imgContainer = new InlineUIContainer();
var img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your_image_url"));
imgContainer.Child = img;
para.Inlines.Add(imgContainer);
para.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Something..." });
richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(para);
```

Or you could write it this way, which more closely mirrors the XAML.

```cs
var richTextBlock = new RichTextBlock()
{
    Blocks = {
        new Paragraph {
            Inlines = {
                new Run { Text = "Something" },
                new InlineUIContainer {
                    Child = new Image {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your_image_url"))
                    }
                },
                new Run { Text = "Something..."}
            }
        }
    }
};
```